# What does this mean in Python?

Tags: python

I'm learning Python.

I'm curious to know what this mean?

```
count = 10**6
```

I try to print the variable "count" but gives me an error.

Can someone give me a clue on this?

Best Regards,

Comment: `count = 10**6; print count; print 10**6;` is completely legal. You should post the full code or the error your getting bumped at.

Comment: How are you trying to print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using Python 3, but are using a tutorial designed for Python 2. In Python 3, `print()` is a function and requires parentheses:

```
print(count)
```

In Python 2, `print` is a statement and can be used without parentheses:

```
print count
```

As always, it would help us if you show the *actual* error you are getting.

Answer (score 5):

`**` in that context is [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation).

Answer (score 4):

`**` is the exponentiation operator, so you are computing 10 to the 6th power. The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary) tabulates the supported operators.

Comment: Except, of course, when it isn't the exponentiation operator.

Comment: Good point. (To clarify, programmers can override the `**` operator by defining a method named [`__pow__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types). Somewhat dangerous because the order of operations can't be changed.)

Comment: There's also the cases where it isn't the binary exponentiation operator at all, for example in `f(**kwargs)`, which is (I expect) what Ignacio meant.

Answer (score 0):

** means exponentiation. Usually that is represented by ^.

In the above example 10**6 will give you a result of 1000000

Comment: Usually? Not in Python. Not in C or C++. Not in C#. Not in Java. So, really, not in any language that matters :-) <-- Note the smiley. But, still, "usually" is an ... interesting ... claim.